# Git:Heroku Repository or object not found:

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, git-lfs

Here is the error message from Heroku master push command

```
Git LFS: (0 of 5 files) 0 B / 167.50 MB                                                                                                    
batch response: Repository or object not found: https://git.heroku.com/xxxx-brushlands-xx267.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/xxxx-brushlands-xx267.git'
```

Added a long text file to Git LFS (git for large files) and after that Heroku stopped working.

What might be the issue ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After alot of googling I found that the problem is with Heroku. If you are using Heroku, then Heroku doesn't support LFS and you have to look for alternatives.

I uploaded my long text file to dropbox and accessing it from there. Heroku should definitely look in to this issue.

Answer (score 13):

A workaround:

```
git push heroku master --no-verify
```

This disables git-lfs pre-push hook. Metadata files are commited but binaries are not uploaded.

Then, as per upendra's answer, a buildpack can be used to download the files.

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary solution to the problem of using Git LFS with Heroku. I am just putting it here just in case if people are still looking for it - https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/805

If that doesn't work, then try this out. This method worked for me - https://github.com/raxod502/heroku-buildpack-git-lfs