# Push large files to git repository hosted on tfs

Tags: git, tfs, git-lfs

I install and config lfs extension on my git repository and track ".ai" files. 
when I push the commit with these files got this error:

```
Git LFS: (0 of 5 files) 0 B / 1.19 GB
batch response: Repository or object not found: <repo url>/objects/batch
Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the repo, could you run `git config --list |grep lfs` and tell us what you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using LFS via SSH, there is a similar issue for your reference [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14278).

There are a couple of reasons why this error can occur:

- You don't have permissions to access certain LFS object

  Check if you have permissions to push to the project or fetch from    the project.
- Project is not allowed to access the LFS object

  LFS object you are trying to push to the project or fetch from the project is not available to the project anymore. Probably the object was removed from the server.
- Wrong version of LFS client used:

  Check the version of Git LFS on the client machine with `git lfs version`. Only version 0.6.0 and newer are supported.
- Local git repository is using deprecated LFS API, Project is using deprecated LFS API

  Check the Git config of the project for traces of deprecated API with `git lfs -l`. If `batch = false` is set in the config, remove the line and try using [Git LFS client](https://git-lfs.github.com/) newer than 0.6.0.

Also , make sure you match the requirements, see [this article](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/lfs/manage_large_binaries_with_git_lfs.html#error-repository-or-object-not-found) for details.
And check if LFS supports for your environment, reference [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822146/githeroku-repository-or-object-not-found).